# How to foreach my RDD/DataFrame and create a dict in the driver?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to collect all the relations from different patitions' rdd/dataframe to a globle dict.

```
my_dict = collections.defaultdict(list) 
    def info_to_dict(rows):
        for row in rows:
            my_dict[row.key].append(row.value)
    df.foreachPartition(info_to_dict)
```

but it doesn't work.
The number of the key is too many to use "reducebyKey".

Now I try this.

```
class DefaultDictParam(AccumulatorParam):
    def zero(self, acc=""):
        return collections.defaultdict(list)
    def addInPlace(self, acc1, acc2):
        for k,v in acc2.items():
            acc1[k].extend(v)
        return acc1
```

But I can't find the guide of that how to add two `collections.defaultdict(list)` as one `collections.defaultdict(list)`.

Comment: Have you tried with collectAsMap() ?

Comment: @RonakJain I need all the values, the count of the key is not satisfied.

Comment: Didn't get you, can you add an example? collectAsMap will give you the whole dataframe as a dict.

Comment: the input like [(1, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)] , I want [(1,[3]),(2,[4,5])] as output.

Comment: In case of dataframes you can first do group and collectList and then collectAsMap

Comment: It makes sense, but the keys are too many. Then OOM error.

Comment: CollectList won't give you OOM, but the problem statement "create a dict in the driver?" essentially means collection of all data of RDD in the driver, which would cause driver OOM.

Comment: If you want to collect a huge dataframe/rdd to the driver, you'll get OOM anyhow.

Comment: maybe the groupby makes my work error, I already tried the groupby:(

Comment: Just groupBy would be this -> spark.createDataFrame([["1","1-val1"], ["1","1-val2"], ["3","3-val1"]]).toDF("id", "key").groupBy("id").agg(F.collect_list("key")).show();

Working for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to group by key and collect a list of the values. Then you want to collect that onto the driver. You can to that with either `collect` that will return a list of tuples, or `collectAsMap` that will return a dictionary that maps keys to their lists of values:

```py
rdd = sc.parallelize([(1, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)])

// returns a list of tuples
rdd.groupByKey().mapValues(list).collect()
```

```
[(1, [3]), (2, [4, 5])]
```

```py
// returns a dictionary
rdd.groupByKey().mapValues(list).collectAsMap()
```

```
{1: [3], 2: [4, 5]}
```